# Parallel.foreach in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a question on Parallel.Foreach in C#. I'm new to multithreading and have started learning it from month. I'm using a Foreach loop and in that foreach loop i'm finding the average of a list of list of integers and adding each average to a cuncurrent bag. But thae problem I'm facing is not all the iteration's results are getting added. My list has 10 entries but the cuncurrent bag i'm adding to has less than ten entries at the end of foreach loop. Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

The below is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<int>> intList = new List<List<int>>();
            List<int> ints = new List<int>();
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k ++)
            {
                ints.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
                {
                    ints.Add(rand.Next(10000000));
                }
                List<int> copy = new List<int>(ints);
                intList.Add(copy);
            }
            ConcurrentBag<double> results = new ConcurrentBag<double>();
            Parallel.ForEach<List<int>, double>(intList,
                () => 0,
                (eachIterationList, pls, threadLocal) =>
                {
                    threadLocal = eachIterationList.Average();
                    return threadLocal;
                },
                    (result) =>
                    {
                        lock (results)
                        {
                            results.Add(result);
                        }
                    });
            Console.WriteLine("No of results in results variable: {0}", results.Count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

The results variable contains less than ten elements when written to console against the ten I think it should be having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see that local finally delegate runs on final action of EVERY task which was used to process the `Parallel.ForEach`. Each time it can be different number. So if you modify your code as listed below, you will see that the number of tasks used for list iteration is same number as the tasks run the final action. This finalization delegate serves different purpose than you need in your case.

You need to understand the difference between Threads and Tasks in .NET.
Also your code was wrong when you used lock to add to ConcurrentBag, because it already supports multithreaded Add to collection and you don't need locking.

```
 List<List<int>> intList = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> ints = new List<int>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
        {
            ints.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                ints.Add(rand.Next(10000000));
            }
            List<int> copy = new List<int>(ints);
            intList.Add(copy);
        }
        HashSet<int?> resultTaskIds = new HashSet<int?>();
        HashSet<int?> iterationTaskIds = new HashSet<int?>();
        ConcurrentBag<double> results = new ConcurrentBag<double>();
        Parallel.ForEach<List<int>, double>(intList,
            () => 0,
            (eachIterationList, pls, threadLocal) =>
            {
                iterationTaskIds.Add(Task.CurrentId);

                return eachIterationList.Average();
            },
                (result) =>
                {
                    resultTaskIds.Add(Task.CurrentId);
                    results.Add(result);
                });
```

Comment: Thank you Ander for your clear explanation, I got my mistake. Yes, locking the concurrentBag isn't necessary, but I had tried without locking but obviously it wasn't working then even so gave it a try with locking, but obviously that didn't work as the cause was completely something else.

Answer (score 0):

Why locking the results ConcurrentBag? Doing simple like this works :

```
        Parallel.ForEach(intList,
            list =>
            {
                results.Add(list.Average());
            });
```

Locking the result doesn't guarantee your items are in the right order.
If you want that both are sync, use this instead:

```
List<double> results = new List<double>(Enumerable.Repeat(0.0d, intList.Count));
Parallel.For(0, intList.Count,
(i) =>
{
   results[i] = intList[i].Average();
});
```

or using .ForEach() :

```
List<double> results = new List<double>(Enumerable.Repeat(0.0d, intList.Count));
Parallel.ForEach(intList,
    (item, loop, i) =>
    {
        results[(int)i] = item.Average();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Arnaud for your answer. But i want to achieve it the way I'm trying to achieve it, I know locking the cuncurrentBag isn't necessary, and I had tried it without locking it, but that wasn't working either, so I went with locking. But, nevertheless, what is wrong with what I'm doing? I'am learning usage of "Parallel.ForEach<List<int>, double>" this particular overload so experimenting with it. Yes this same thing can be achived using other solutions of yours but I really want to find out what is wrong with what I'm doing.

Comment: The 'localFinally' is not called once per item but once per Thread used to compute the Parallel.ForEach tasks. 
More here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f1462148-1b34-4f67-ba10-cb9b8bb9505c/parallelaggregation-localfinally-not-getting-called-enough-times?forum=parallelextensions

Comment: Or here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420227/why-does-the-localinit-func-get-called-multiple-times-per-thread-in-parallel-for

Comment: Thank you! I got my mistake.